# basis vectors of a 2D lattice plane in a 3D lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know the basis vectors of the three-dimensional lattice $\Lambda = \{\mathbf{b_1}, \mathbf{b_2}, \mathbf{b_3} \}$. I also know the equation of the plane in this 3D lattice, suppose $Ax + By + Cz = 0$. Is there a method to obtain the basis vectors of the 2D lattice $(\Lambda_{2D})$ that exists on this plane? Currently, I am thinking of generating many of the lattice points on the plane and then picking two shortest vectors in non-orthogonal directions and passing it through a lattice reduction algorithm to obtain the basis. This seems to be a trail-and-error based method and I feel that there should be a better way to tackle this problem. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I would really appreciate if the person who down-voted the question could please tell me the reasoning behind doing so! This is not a homework question and if the down-voting is because there is a trivial solution, I would really appreciate hints toward that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that my attempt to answer this question generates some interest in this problem.

Suppose, the 3D lattice is $\mathbb{Z}^3$. Suppose the basis vectors in the 2D lattice are $\{\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{y_1}\} = \Lambda_{2D}$. Therefore, $Ax_1 + Bx_2 + Cx_3 = 0$ and $Ay_1 + By_2 + Cy_3 = 0$. The condition that the 2D basis vectors have to satisfy is that the area covered by the parallelogram formed by the vectors $\{\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{y_1}\}$ should be a minimum and greater than zero.

Since, there are infinite combinations possible, suppose the components of $\mathbf{x_1}$ are $(0, -C/m, B/m)$ (where $m = gcd(B,C)$). The area of the parallelogram is given by the norm of the cross product $\mathbf{x_1} \times \mathbf{y_1}$.

\begin{align}
\mathbf{x_1} \times \mathbf{y_1} &= -\frac{(Cy_3 + By_2 )}{m}\mathbf{e_x} + \frac{By_1}{m}\mathbf{e_x} + \frac{Cy_1}{m}\mathbf{e_z} \\
&= \frac{Ay_1}{m}\mathbf{e_x} + \frac{By_1}{m}\mathbf{e_x} + \frac{Cy_1}{m}\mathbf{e_z}
\end{align}

The area is $y_1^2 \left( \frac{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}{m^2}\right)$, which is proportional to $y_1$. Hence, the area is minimized if $|y_1|$ is minimized and $y_1 \neq 0$. In the sequence $y_1 = \pm1, \pm2, \ldots$, $y_1$ is chosen such that there exist integer solutions for the Diophantine equation $By_2 + Cy_3 = -Ay_1$. Therefore, $y_1$ is the smallest possible natural number such that  $gcd(B,C)|Ay_1$. Once $y_1$ is obtained, $y_2$ and $y_3$ are solved for the integer solutions of $By_2 + Cy_3 = -Ay_1$. Hence, the bases may be obtained.

I was wondering if this could be generalized to any 3D lattice with basis $\Lambda_{3D} = \{\mathbf{b_1}, \mathbf{b_2}, \mathbf{b_3}\}$. I realize that I will have to get a compact form of the norm of the cross product in this new basis. I am not yet sure how that would look like. I wonder if anyone has any suggestions!

Comment: After trying to generalize to an arbitrary 3D basis, I obtained a really compact equation for the area of the parallelogram mentioned in this answer. The area is still proportional to $y_1^2$ and hence the above method holds for any basis.