# Projecting a 3D lattice to 2D lattice considering a given plane

Tags: plane-geometry, crystallography

I have a lattice in 3D with $a$, $b$ and $c$ being its unit vectors. Say we have a simple cubic crystal then $a = (1, 0, 0)$, $b = (0, 1, 0)$ and $c = (0, 0, 1)$ are its building blocks. In principle, this is a periodic structure such that I have hundreds of these cubes where the distance between the cubes obviously is $a$ in $x$-direction ....

Now, I am supposed to project this 3D structure to a given plane and build a new 2D periodic structure with new unit vectors ($a'$ and $b'$) which should be derived from the old $a$, $b$ and $c$.

My problem is in finding the correct $a'$ and $b'$.

To make it clear I give you a simple example:

Suppose the plane is constructed based on two vectors $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 0)$ meaning that the plane normal vector is $(0, 0, 1)$ or in the other words we are in $xy$ plane. So, as we know the coordinates in the $xy$ plane then simply the $a' = a$ and $b' = b$.

The point is not always as simple as this example. So, let's say the two vectors forming the plane are $(0, 1, 1)$ and $(1, 1, 0)$ then the normal vector is $(1, -1, 1)$ and obviously, we cannot simply say we are in $xy$ or $xz$ or $yz$ plane. So, what is the best way to compute the new $a'$ and $b'$ in such situations?

I am not a mathematician so sorry if this is a trivial question. I have spent so much time on that and would greatly appreciate any help!

Dave

Comment: Are $a'$ and $b'$ also meant to be 3D vectors or 2D vectors in some convenient coordinate system on the plane?

Comment: As you have mentioned in the last part of the sentence, they should be 2D. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, a way to get started is to construct a rotation that “tilts” the plane’s normal to align it with the $z$-axis. Rotate each of the principal vectors of the lattice and drop the last coordinate to get their projections onto the plane. Since you’re only rotating three vectors, Rodrigues’ rotation formula might be less work than constructing a suitable matrix.

Comment: I tried the things you've mentioned but I don't get the right things. Actually, my answer to your question has not been informative enough. This question should be solved in two-step: (1) find a' and b' in terms of old a, b, c (here a' and b' can have three non-zero elements); (2) as you've mentioned rotating to get rid of one of the components. My point is how to derive the right dependency of a' and b' to a, b and c. Thanks!

Comment: I see. There are going to be many choices for $a'$ and $b'$—the unit cell of the resulting mesh is not unique—but they’re all simple linear combinations of the projections of $a$, $b$ and $c$. As this is essentially a two-dimensional problem, I think it will make things easier to first apply the rotation and projection that I described, work out the mesh parameters in 2D, and then transform back into 3D, which just involves rotating back.

Comment: Hmm... I’m not convinced that the projected grid is even periodic in the general case. Are there any additional conditions on either the lattice or the plane? For example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/852491/265466) only considers planes of the lattice.

Comment: Incidentally, MathJax is used to format mathematical expressions on this site. I’ve taken the liberty of editing your question to add this formatting, but in the future you should do that yourself. You can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @amd thanks very much for editing the post and for the useful comments on my question. Yes, the projected grid should be periodic because I am supposed to make a 2D periodic structure out of this 3D periodic structure. The only things I know are the unit cell vectors in 3D, the two vectors forming the plane and the normal vector of the plane. For the 3D, I  also do have the three angles (between a and b; between a and c and between b and c). What kind of condition should I consider to preserve the periodicity on the 2D plane?